# Take a screenshot during dragging in Appium

Tags: android, automation, screenshot, appium

In Android, I need to drag an object in my app and take a screenshot WHILE STILL HOLDING the object.

I know that there are two ways of using touch actions (I'm not even considering the higher-level methods such as `swipe()` as they give me much less control over my touch actions):

```
new TouchAction(driver).press(element).moveTo(x,y).release().perform();
```

and

```
driver.performTouchAction(new TouchAction(driver).press(element).moveTo(x,y).release());
```

When I try to divide my touch action into two parts, and inserting a screenshot capture in between as in the code below:

```
new TouchAction(driver)
    .press(x,y)
    .moveTo(newX,newY)
    .perform();

takeScreenshot(); // My own implementation for readability 

new TouchAction(driver)
    .release()
    .perform();
```

I get the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: ERROR running Appium command: Cannot read property 'x' of null
Command duration or timeout: 14 milliseconds
```

The program fails during the second touch action, i.e., the screenshot is being successfully taken, but I have no way of releasing the object after grabbing it in this manner.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your question

```
new TouchAction(driver)
    .release()
    .perform();
```

for release provide some x and y location to release have a try might work

Comment: Not sure I understand you correctly, but if you're suggesting that I try .release(x, y), there is no such method (at least in the Java client of Appium).

Comment: Even though I couldn't use your answer directly, you steered me in the right direction, so thank you very much! My final code looks like this:
`touchAction.moveTo(0,0).release().perform();`
where touchAction refers to the first TouchAction object:
`TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver).press(x,y). etc...`
By using a reference to the same touchAction, and by "moving" the coordinates by 0, I was able to complete the second action.