# Appuim - Long press and take screenshot at the same time

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

is Appium capable of long press and taking screenshot at the same time?

```
 public void press(By by) throws IOException {
    WebElement el = driver.findElement(by);
    TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
    action.longPress(el);}
```

After that I apply take screenshot

```
  public void screenshot(String filename) throws IOException {
    File srcFile=driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    File targetFile=new File("./Screenshots/Navigation/" + generateCurrentDate()+ "/"+ filename +".jpg");
    FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile,targetFile);}
```

But it performs long press and after that takes screenshot. I need basically long press and screenshot at the same time.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Maybe something here can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34201207/take-a-screenshot-during-dragging-in-appium

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved that

```
    public void pressByElements(By by, int num) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    List<WebElement> el = driver.findElements(by);
    TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
    action.press(el.get(num)).waitAction(2000).perform();

}
```

And then you can take a pic. But only when I want to release that element from hold, it gives me error. For now I don't mind to release that. Fine for now